# libuvc_camera: Library not loaded with indigo on osx

Tags: ros, libuvc-camera, ros-indigo, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

when it try to run my webcam with libuvc_camera:

```
sudo -E rosrun libuvc_camera camera_node vendor:=0x046d
dyld: Library not loaded: librospack.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/ros/indigo/bin/rospack
  Reason: image not found
```

But librospack.dylib is compiled fresh and sitting in /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librospack.dylib.
Why is it not being found? Is there something wrong with my paths?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186492/libuvc_camera:-library-not-loaded-with-indigo-on-osx/) by [J.M.T.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3816/j.m.t./) on ROS Answers with karma: 266 on 2014-07-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-07-14**:
I guess with your answer to your other question you don't need to resolve this any more?

**Comment by [J.M.T.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3816/j.m.t./) on 2014-07-15**:
No, unfortunately this still needs to be resolved. I gave up the isight but really need a camera. Thus I've settled for a fairly standard Logitech c270...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would start by not using `sudo`, which is not well supported by rosrun. Does the error persist?

If you don't have permission to access the device, change them temporarily using `chmod`, or permanently with `udev`.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [J.M.T.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3816/j.m.t./) on 2014-07-15**:
You are right, i only tried sudo -E  because it was recommended in the wiki. Of course I tried without sudo before but had a different error:

**Comment by [J.M.T.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3816/j.m.t./) on 2014-07-15**:
ros::InvalidNameException: Character [0] is not valid as the first character in Graph Resource Name [0x046d]. Turned out the leading 0 in 0x046d was the real problem.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-07-15**:
For the record, could you state the command line invocation that worked for you (dealing with the leading 0)?

**Comment by [J.M.T.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3816/j.m.t./) on 2014-07-15**:
Sure, rosrun libuvc_camera camera_node vendor:=x046d

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-07-15**:
Ah ok, thanks!

**Comment by [zipper1956](https://answers.ros.org/users/19945/zipper1956/) on 2014-08-10**:
Thanks! It works for me!